# How do I see the source code of Notepad++?

Tags: source-code

I have downloaded and installed Notepad++ and it is working fine. I hear it is open source. How do I see the source code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Notepad++ support question, not a question relevant to people who participate in open source projects. See [this meta thread](https://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/150/are-questions-about-specific-software-on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [downloads page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.9.2.html) lists a source code download (the last download on the list). The link points to a [GitHub release](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/tag/v6.7.9.2) of the current version.

It's mostly written in C++, so you will need some method of compiling it if you want to run and modify it. Personally, I use MS Visual Studio 2013 because of its multi-language capabilities.

To be notified of when a new version of the source code comes out, you can watch the GitHub repository and a notification will be delivered to your GH account whenever it is updated.

Answer (score 2):

The source code to notepad ++ can be downloaded [here.](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.9.2.html/)

The link is the last bulletin under the download button.

Note, if you want to edit and run the product you will need to use a compiler.